# Switching Bluetooth SCO (headset) device when multiple are connected

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I'm working on getting bluetooth working in my app for VoIP calls, and I can get the headset connected and playing correctly.

I'm using a combination of listening for Bluetooth Headset changes as well as using the Bluetooth profile proxy to see which headsets are connected.

When I call get the proxy,

```
 mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(context, pofileListener, BluetoothProfile.HEADSET)
```

> https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter#getProfileProxy(android.content.Context,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener,%20int)

I get a list of the currently connected bluetooth headset devices, and it tells me which one is connected to Audio with a boolean flag

> https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHeadset#isAudioConnected(android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice)

I can't figure out how to change the audio source though? I want to show these two connected devices in a dialog and let the user choose between them.

I can physically turn one or the other device on/off and the audio transitions smoothly every time, I just want to let the user choose where the audio goes.

Comment: So it looks like maybe I can keep a reference to the bluetooth devices and use reflection to call the disconnect/connect methods in BluetoothHeadset.  The isAudioConnected seems unreliable though as I'm sometimes getting different values than what I'm hearing audio from...  Will update if I can make it work.

Comment: So far this is completely unreliable as well... works sometimes, doesn't work other times, audio mode changes unexpectedly resulting in different audio quality on the same bluetooth device.